# How to refresh only PHP header file using JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to reload only the header file instead of total page using JavaScript/jQuery. My code is below.

```
<?php
 require_once('include/listspace_header.php');
?>
<div class="popover-content">
<p>                            
<select class="chosen-select text-left" style="width:100%;"  onchange="setCountry();" id="conid">
<option value="" selected>Select Country</option>
<?php
    foreach ($country as $v) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $v['country_id']; ?>"><?php echo $v['country_name']; ?></option>
<?php
 }
?>
</select>
</p>
</div>
```

Here I need to reload only `include/listspace_header.php` page using JavaScript/jQuery rather than the total page.

Comment: Php runs at server so Either you use ajax or send the file again to the server.

Comment: ir is impossible. Even you will update part of html with ajax, remainig php code will not be refreshed

Comment: use ajax to get the header page and place it on header part

Comment: @JYoThI : Can you please edit your idea which you want to explain ?

Answer (score 0):

What about simply putting it inside a div, for example:

**Inside listspace_header.php:**

```
echo '<div id="headerReload">';
----- LISTSPACE_HEADER.PHP CONTENT -----
echo '</div>';
```

and then using `load()` method to get the file again, most likely with updated data? like so:

```
$(".chosen-select").change(function() {
    $(".headerReload").load('include/listspace_header.php');
)};
```

**EDIT:**

Well, the code i provided above would unfortunatelly lead to doubling, tripling and multiplying forever the `div id="headerRealod"`, so I think it would be even better to set this `div` markup around your `php require_once` code in the basic file.

Comment: @satya maybe you have `<html>` or `<head>` tags in this `listspace_header.php` file? If yes, then instead of `<div id="headerReload">` try to use `<iframe id="headerReload"></iframe>` markup and let us know if it worked.

Comment: @satya i guess we would need to see the included PHP file to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to trigger the php code from the JavaScript. Once the HTTP data sent to the client browser there is no way using JavaScript to tell PHP reload file added using server side includes and update the portion of the web page already sent to the client browser. Instead, You will use Ajax to fetch the contents of `listspace_header.php` file and push them into the header dynamically.

Here is example below using jquery

```
<div id='header'>
<?php
 require_once('include/listspace_header.php');
?>
</div>

<button id='reloadHeader'>Reload Header</button>

<div class="popover-content">
<p>                            
<select class="chosen-select text-left" style="width:100%;"  onchange="setCountry();" id="conid">
<option value="" selected>Select Country</option>
<?php
    foreach ($country as $v) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $v['country_id']; ?>"><?php echo $v['country_name']; ?></option>
<?php
 }
?>
</select>
</p>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//Button Click Event to Reload header file 
 $('#reloadHeader').click(function(){

  //Send Ajax Request to get the contents of header file 
  $.ajax({url: "include/listspace_header.php", success: function(result){
     $('#header').html(result);
  });  

 });

});
```

Comment: Its throwing this `GET http://localhost/fyndspace/include/listspace_header.php 500 (Internal Server Error)`. Actually my header file contains all header html part with js/css link and some code from body part.

Comment: Change the path to the correct url. Where your listspace_header.php is located ? It looks like you are trying to achieve something in wrong way. Why you need to refresh the header ?

Comment: No,path is correct. because my header is coming while reload the file. But when I am running this file using the address bar its showing the message the local host page is not working.